# problems with my submit

Tags: php, html, mysqli

I'm using multiple forms to select what to update. only my last form disappears after submitting. I don't think it even processes the update it should do on submit.
please help me!

php code:

```
if ($collect == "foto"){

                            $sql = mysqli_query($link, "SELECT * FROM foto");
                            $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($sql);
                            $array = array();


                                echo "<form method='POST'>";
                                while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($sql))
                                {
                                    echo "<input type='text' name='foto[]' value=".htmlspecialchars($row['foto'])."></input>";
                                }
                                echo "<input type='submit' name='submit3' value='update'></input></form>";

                                if (isset($_POST['submit3'])) {
                                    echo "Finally!";
                                    $array = $_POST['foto'];
                                    $i = 0;
                                     foreach ($array as $foto) {
                                     $ufoto = $array[$i];
                                     $sql ="
                                        UPDATE
                                            foto
                                        SET
                                            foto = '$ufoto'
                                        WHERE 
                                            id = $i
                                        ";
                                    mysqli_query($link, $sql);
                                    $i ++;

                                    var_dump($array);
                                    }
                                }   
                            }
```

Comment: From what I can see, you only open a form once; you have no `where` clause in your update, so it would put them all to be the same thing, you should at least pass along an `id` or some of field to differentiate. Aside from that, I'm not really sure what you say is going wrong.

Comment: @jon without a where statement in the update it updates all right? that's the purpose. also the problem I'm having is that when I press submit nothing happends.

Comment: So in the `foto` table, you have a field named `foto` that you want every single one in the database changed to the input text?  If so, how you plan on doing it will update them all to the last one in the array as you have nothing else to distinguish it from the others.

Comment: @Jon Good point, Maybe that's why it's not working, Ill try to give it an variable ID to update them all

Comment: @Jon I changed it, This should work. but the issue still stands. can you take another look?

Comment: You'll also want to change `$_POST['foto'] = $array['foto'];` to `$array = $_POST['foto'];`

Comment: @jon thanks for the help so far. I changed all the things you said but for some reason it still doesnt update.. after I click update the whole thing dissapears and the button still is not set.

Comment: Can you edit the question to show what you have? ^^

Comment: @jon I updated the code :) this is what I got so far..

Comment: @jon I found the solution! turns out because this form is a part of another selection menu on refresh it doesnt reload this page. Solved it using sessions. Thank you so much for helping me :)

Comment: Glad you got it working ^^

Answer (score 1):

```
$_POST['foto'] = $array['foto'];
```

should most likely be:

```
$array = $_POST['foto'];
```

your script is also open to SQL injection attacks.

Answer (score 0):

Before the edit I saw you neglected to put an `action`-attribute in your `form`-tag. This action attribute specifies which php-site should process the form.

See more here: http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_form_action.asp

Comment: If the `action` is undefined, it submits to itself.

Comment: `In HTML5, the action attribute is no longer required.` - it will submit to itself it the action attribute is omitted.